# Reverse a query hint in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2017, and I was trying to optimize a query that runs slowly. Surfing some blogs, I came across query hints and used this one:

```
option(use hint('DISABLE_OPTIMIZED_NESTED_LOOP'), maxdop 1);
```

Unfortunately, what happened is now the query runs even slower, and I couldn't figure out how to reverse the effect of this hint.

My questions are:

1- Does this hint affect other users and their queries too?

2- How to restore the query optimizer to its default settings?

Comment: Just remove the hint you added to revert. A resource-intensive query, hint or not, can affect other queries in your workload.

Comment: I removed it, but the query still runs slower than before (it used to execute in 10 mins, now more than 30 mins, even without the hint). Is the query optimizer changed permanently by this hint, or just at the time of execution only ?

Comment: I assume you you are not using the query store to fix a specific plan. In that case, a new query plan is generated when it's compiled after a change. The new plan could be better or worse than the original cached one. Is the query parameterized? Upload the actual plan to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the link to your question for help with troubleshooting its performance.

Comment: Is the query part of stored procedure ?

Comment: No it is just a query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- Does this hint affect other users and their queries too??

**No**

2- How to restore the query optimizer to its default settings??

**Removing hint, if the execution plan is still the same put OPTION (RECOMPILE) or if you have a stored procedure run sp_recompile ‘yoursp’**

Comment: Thanks Gabriele! the OPTION(RECOMPILE) works fine as long as it is kept in the query. Once you remove it, the bad performance returns. This is due to the fact that it does not force the new query plan into the cache, hence the old 'bad' query plan will be used again when you remove the option. Is there a way to delete the 'bad' query plan from the cache ?

Comment: You can have a trouble with incorrect estimates. Check: missing statitistics, out of date statistics, poor statistics sample rate, parameter sniffing behavior.

Comment: Great, updating table statistics solved the problem,, thanks a lot :)